# Choosing subsample size (helping a friend analysing a smaller data set)

Tags: classification, subsampling

A friend of mine is working analysing 2000 twits per day and categorize them as postive, negative or neutral. 
This is a really boring task but the algorithms that do this classification are not very good because they can't detect sarcasm.
A simple solution to make more easy this task is to do a subsample of the original $N = 2000$ data points.

Doing some tests we saw that with $30\%$ of the data the normalized histograms of the subsample and the original data points look very similar but we need to know a better estimation of the error of doing this subsample.

Theoretically the data points are an i.i.d. sequence $(X_i)_{i=1}^N$ (big assumption) in the space $A = \{0,1,2\}$ (positive,negative,neutral). Let $(X_{(i)})_{i=1}^n$ be a subsample  of size $n \leq N$  (draw $n$ elements uniformly without replacement).
In some sense I want to characterize the distribution of $(X_{(i)})_{i=1}^n$ in order to choose a $n$ such that the empirical distribution of $(X_{(i)})_{i=1}^n$  is close to the empirical distribution of $(X_i)_{i=1}^N$.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: An excellent answer has been given to a similar problem [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142175/sample-size-for-categorical-data). Thompson's method allows one to identify the minimum worst-case sample size required to maintain subsample proportions within a specific distance of the originals. The implementation is quite easy. Happy analysis!

Comment: user90803, if you agree that the question found by @AlexFirsov duplicates yours, please let us (the moderators) know, because we can get you your bounty back (at least if you take action before it expires).  If it is not a duplicate, then could you indicate how the two questions differ and why your needs a separate answer?

Comment: @whuber tagging you so you see user90803's comment