# Power analysis for multinomial logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-power, multinomial-distribution

I am planning a regression analysis where a continuous independent variable predicts 3 categorical outcomes of a dependent variable. I believe this is done using multinomial logistic regression. Before I go ahead and collect my data I would like to get an idea of the sample size I will need to to have an adequately powered analysis. I have not been able to find much information about how to conduct a power analysis for a multinomial logistic regression.

My questions are as follows:

1. is a multinomial logistic regression the right statistic for this scenario?
2. if so, how to conduct a power analysis for multinomial regression?

Comment: This problem is very complicated and here is an answer to a very related problem: [Sample size for categorical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142795/103153). And this function would be helpful: [MultinomCI](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/DescTools/html/MultinomCI.html).