# How to determine sample size when performing indirect sampling?

Tags: categorical-data, sample-size, multinomial-distribution

### Problem Summary

I want to know the minimum sample size needed for a given confidence level and margin of error when performing indirect sampling where samples from the two populations are not one-to-one.

### More Details

I would like to sample from a population $P$ of finite size which is unknown and assumed to be large. Each element in $P$ can be classified into one of a finite number of categories. However, I can't sample $P$ directly.

Instead, I must sample from a different population $P'$ of finite size which is known and large. Each element in $P'$ can be classified into one of a finite number of categories.

To derive $P$ from $P'$, do the following:

> Group all $p'=(a',b',c')$ in $P'$ by their $a'$ values. Then, for each $a'$,
> there is a corresponding $p = (x,y)$ in $P$ where
>
> - $x = 0$ if all corresponding $p'$s have matching $b'$ values, else $1$
> - $y = 0$ if all corresponding $p'$s have matching $c'$ values, else $1$

Here's an example. Let $S'$ be a set of samples from $P'$ and $S$ be a set of samples which we want to represent samples in $P$.

```
    S' = (0,5,5), (5,1,2), (4,0,4), (0,5,4), (5,3,4), (2,5,0), (2,7,0), (3,2,8), (1,1,2), (4,0,4)
    Then create groups based on a':
        (a',b',c'), ...         (x,y)
        -----------------------------
        ( 0, 5, 5), (0,5,4) --> (0,1)
        ( 1, 1, 2)          --> (0,0)
        ( 2, 5, 0), (2,7,0) --> (1,0)
        ( 3, 2, 8)          --> (0,0)
        ( 4, 0, 4), (4,0,4) --> (0,0)
        ( 5, 1, 2), (5,3,4) --> (1,1)
    S  = (0,1), (0,0), (1,0), (0,0), (0,0), (1,1)
```

How do I compute the minimum size of $S'$ needed for a given confidence level and margin of error for the sample proportions of each category in $S$ (generated using the method described above)?

### Research

Assuming I were sampling directly, this [Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142795) post seems to be a good starting point for determining a sample size I'd need to collect for a given confidence level and margin of error for each category's sample proportion.

For a given $S'$, in generating $S$, we are likely to undercount $(1,1)$s and overcount $(0,0)$s compared to a true sampling of $P$. Consider, for a given $a'$, there may exist an element in $P'$ which, if sampled, would have resulted in the corresponding element in $S$ being $(1,1)$ instead of $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, or $(0,0)$. Similarly, $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ instead of $(0,0)$.

I've seen the [Generalized Weight Share Method](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/catalogue/12-001-X20060029551) mentioned for performing indirect sampling, but need a more dumbed down explanation.